# Forticlient "Error unpacking image file"

Tags: installation

I have downloaded the Forticlient Online Installer from https://forticlient.com/downloads and try to run it. The image file gets downloaded fine but when it tried to unpack it I get the error

```
Error unpacking image file
```

I've tried to search for an answer but they all point to using the offline installer. I have tried to get the offline installer from Fortinet support but they are being really unhelpful and refuse to give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps to fix**

1. Go to the directory `C:\ProgramData` (you'll have to allow windows explorer to show hidden items)
2. Look for a file called `Applications`. No extension, thats the entire filename.
3. Rename it to `Applicationsx`
4. Try running the Forticlient installer again
5. Go back to `C:\ProgramData`
6. Delete the **directory** `C:\ProgramData\Applications` (this is just used by the Forticlient installer)
7. Rename the **file** `C:\ProgramData\Applicationsx` back to `Applications`

**Reason**

Forticlient installer unpacks the download file to a directory `C:\ProgramData\Application`. This conflicts with a file that already exists. Forticlient can't do anythign about it and fails.

This problem would have been easier to fix if Fortinet Customer Support would have just given me the offline installer. They refused to do so because I wasn't a subscriber.

Just to add, I figured it out with help from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oPoyn54sTE. The video also tells you how to get the offline installer that Fortinet Customer Support refused to give me.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same error while installing Forticlient. I solved it by simply running the extension file I downloaded as an administrator. The installation completed successfully without any "error unpackaging image file"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

for the above error, you just give the user rights in root drive (c:/)
then try to install with admin rights.
hopefully, it will install successfully.
I have done this activity successfully.